# bpopup onClose not firing with close

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

Seem to be having an issue with the onClose event not firing when calling the close function manually.

Calling the popup

```
$('#messageBoxPopup').bPopup({
                    easing: 'easeOutBack',
                    speed: 450,
                    onClose: function () {
                        alert('clear');
                        $('#messageBoxContent').html('');
                    }
                });
```

Closing the popup

```
$('#messageBoxPopup').bPopup().close();
```

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem!! Will post back if I manage to sort it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#messageBoxPopup').bPopup().close();
```

working fine for me please check for all js dependencies for bpopup